# How to implement Firebase notification in Eclipse for android?

Tags: android

i am trying to implement Firebase notification for android notification in eclipse but i didn't get specific jar, if any one did this in eclipse please do help for the same.

Comment: read firebase documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can migrate your project on Android studio because Android studio is official IDE for android development and the eclipse is no more supported by the Android development so go for it.